# iOS Safari open link in private tab group

Tags: ios, safari, tabs

When I long-touch a link in Safari on iOS, it shows a command called `Open in Tab Group`... but the `Private` tab group is nowhere to be found in the list of Tab groups.

Am I missing something or has Apple decided that nobody would ever want to do this for any good reason and so neither should I?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the easiest ways to open a link in a private tab group is to use drag-and-drop or copy and paste it. There's no way to do it from the context menu and I'm also curious why.